# Jagged Array in C (3D)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack, jagged-arrays

How could I do the following?

```
double layer1[][3] = {
    {0.1,0.1,0.8},
    {0.1,0.1,0.8},
    {0.1,0.1,0.8},
    {0.1,0.1,0.8}
};
double layer2[][5] = {
    {0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.8}
};
double *upper[] = {layer1, layer2};
```

I read the following after trying different ideas; to no avail.
[Do jagged arrays exist in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083658/jagged-array-in-c)

I understand (I hope) that

```
double **upper[] = {layer1, layer2};
```

Is similar to what I'd like, but would not work because the layers are not arrays of pointers. I am using C intentionally.

---

I am trying to abstain from doing this (which works).

```
double l10[] = {0.1,0.1,0.8};
//l11 etc
double *l1[] = {l10,l11,l12,l13};
double l20[] = {0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.8};
double *l2[] = {l20};

double **both[] = {l1, l2};
```

Comment: You claim this is C, yet you're using `cout`.

Comment: Cause of habit, irrelevant - fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern C there is a tool call *compound literal* to achieve at least partially what you seem to want:

```
double (*(layer1[])) = {
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8},
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8},
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8},
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8}
};
double (*(layer2[])) = {
    (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.8}
};
double (*(*(upper[]))) = {layer1, layer2};
```

I have put in `()` to the types to show you the rules of bindings for the types. But beware that with this type of programming you'd always have to remember the array bounds by yourself.

**Edit:** A construct as `(double[]){ 0.0 }` is called a compound literal and as the same effect as your temporary arrays that you had declared in your second version. The advantage is that you don't have to invent a naming convention for them and that the only way to access these temporary variables is then through the bigger array. Maybe it would be better to put in `const` into all of this so you wouldn't accidentally change the pointers:

```
double (*const(layer1[])) = {
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8},
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8},
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8},
  (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.8}
};
double (*const(layer2[])) = {
    (double[]){0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.8}
};
double (*const(*const(upper[]))) = {layer1, layer2};
```

This still lets you change the contents (all the `doubles`) but not the pointers. If you know that the `doubles` themselves don't change during the whole program, change `double` into `double const` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is for a very specific application and the bounds are always known at compilation and stored in constants.

May I ask how the (double[]) has actually affected how the array is handled?

Comment: @Daniel: e.g. `layer1` is no longer of type `double[][3]`, it's now of type ` double *[]`.  i.e. it's an array of pointers to `double`.  `sizeof` will work differently now, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct {
  size_t length;
  size_t stride;
  double *data;
} upper = {
  {
    sizeof(layer1) / sizeof(layer1[0]),
    sizeof(layer1[0]) / sizeof(layer1[0][0]),
    (double *)layer1,
  },
  {
    sizeof(layer2) / sizeof(layer2[0]),
    sizeof(layer2[0]) / sizeof(layer2[0][0]),
    (double *)layer2,
  },
};

int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(upper) / sizeof(upper[0]); i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < upper[i].length; j++) {
    for (k = 0; i < upper[i].stride; k++)
      printf(" %d" + !k, upper[i].data[upper[i].stride * j + k]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

You have to realize that multi-dimensional arrays in C are just row-major packed into linear piece of storage.  The actual dimensions are only known by the types at compile-time: they're not anywhere to be found in data at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Layer1 and Layer2 are arrays of pointers, by very definition of jagged arrays.
There is no reason for

```
double ** upper[] = {layer1, layer2}
```

Not to work. If it doesn't, post the error message.

The only problem is that your arrays decay to pointers. If that is a problem to you you need to use C99 and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083658/jagged-array-in-c/1090403#1090403) in the thread you already mentioned.

Comment: No they aren't, arrays layer1, layer2 are by very definition arrays of arrays. (Error shown is below, thanks to ephemient)

Comment: Doesn't work. `layer1` has type `double[4][3]` (which decays to `double*[3]`, not `double**`), and similarly for `layer2`.

Comment: In C, there is little explicit difference between an array an a pointer (there are differences, but it's to far to explain them here)
But I must say I haven't tested it myself, time to start up lill' old compiler :)

Comment: I understand that, but there is no explicit declaration of a pointer here, therefore what you posted would not work. As far as I understand it anyway.

Comment: Jens's post showed perfectly what I meant, just vote him up :)