# Is something similar possible in C++

Tags: java, c++

Here is some sample jave code. Is this possible in C++ too?

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[][] a = new int[3][];
        a[0] = new int[]{1};
        a[1] = new int[]{1,2};
        a[2] = new int[]{1,2,3};
        display(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, using pointers.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Why do you feel it's not possible in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jagged array in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083658/jagged-array-in-c)

Comment: I would like to know how.. sorry for not making my point clear in first place

Comment: BTW, depending on what you're trying to do, C++ probably offers a better way not involving dynamic allocation.

Comment: @SharadSharma, it's not entirely clear what you want to do.

Comment: 1. Look at `std::array` and `std::vector`. 2. Mix and match, depending on your needs.

Comment: I am just trying to make an unsymmetrical array, cause in Java it is easy, i am not sure how to do this in C++, I am new to C++. Sorry if I am not able to make my point clear.

Comment: @SharadSharma, look into the std library's iterable containers.  You can do what you want easily using `std::list` or `std::array` or `std::deque` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a pointer to pointers, alike argv that you receive from main(char **argv, ... argc)

a string is a array of chars, and argv is an pointer for that scructure.

You should use int **a, then create line by line in memory,

a should point:

```
a[0] => unnamed pointer => 0, 0, 0
a[1] => unnamed pointer => 0, 0
```

like when you do

```
argv[0] = "my program's name"
argv[1] = "my first param"
```

when whe use char strings there's an '\0' char at the end, so it's possible to know when it finishes, in that case must have some king of control, unlike Java in C you can overflow.

Comment: I think I can do this, sounds a bit tricky as I am a Java programmer, but I think I can manage it.. thanks:)

Comment: That will work, sure, but it's needlessly complicated.  Don't use C++ to program in C. :(

Comment: Read about malloc, if you're in C++ use new witch is more simple and can handle constructors, so something like: int *pointer_to_line = new int[ 10 ] // for ten cols, then make int **a points to pointer_to_line ( a[0] = pointer_to_line ), ok you've done with this line, next line the same thing. for a[1], etc.

Comment: They are coming from Java and even if they weren't I'd still recommend the object oriented solution of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` first for C++

Answer (score 7):

If the question is: "Is it possible to do X in Turing Complete Language Y when it can be done in Turing Complete Language Z?"  Then answer is yes.  It's always yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It is possible.  You can do everything in C++.

Comment: It's what Linus Torvald said of C actually.