# Array to pointer decay and passing multidimensional arrays to functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, callstack

I know that an array decays to a pointer, such that if one declared

```
char things[8];
```

and then later on used `things` somewhere else, `things` is a pointer to the first element in the array.

Also, from my understanding, if one declares

```
char moreThings[8][8];
```

then `moreThings` is *not* of type pointer to char but of type "array of pointers to char," because the decay only occurs once.

When `moreThings` is passed to a function (say with prototype `void doThings(char thingsGoHere[8][8])` what is actually going on with the stack?

If `moreThings` is not of pointer type, then is this really still a pass-by-reference?  I guess I always thought that `moreThings` still represented the base address of the multidimensional array.  What if `doThings` took input `thingsGoHere` and itself passed it to another function?

Is the rule pretty much that unless one specifies an array input as `const` then the array will always be modifiable?

I know that the type checking stuff only happens at compile time, but I'm still confused about what technically counts as a pass by reference (i.e. is it only when arguments of type pointer are passed, or would array of pointers be a pass-by-reference as well?)

Sorry to be a little all over the place with this question, but because of my difficulty in understanding this it is hard to articulate a precise inquiry.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You got it slightly wrong: `moreThings` also decays to a pointer to the first element, but since it is an array of an array of chars, the first element is an "array of 8 chars". So the decayed pointer is of this type:

```
char (*p)[8] = moreThings;
```

The *value* of the pointer is of course the same as the value of `&moreThings[0][0]`, i.e. of the first element of the first element, and also the same of `&a`, but the *type* is a different one in each case.

Here's an example if `char a[N][3]`:

```
+===========================+===========================+====
|+--------+--------+-------+|+--------+--------+-------+|
|| a[0,0] | a[0,1] | a[0,2]||| a[1,0] | a[1,1] | a[1,2]|| ...
|+--------+--------+-------+++--------+--------+-------++ ...
|            a[0]           |            a[1]           |
+===========================+===========================+====
                                    a
^^^
||+-- &a[0,0]
|+-----&a[0]
+-------&a
```

- `&a`: address of the entire array of arrays of chars, which is a `char[N][3]`
- `&a[0]`, same as `a`: address of the first element, which is itself a `char[3]`
- `&a[0][0]`: address of the first element of the first element, which is a `char`

This demonstrates that different objects may have the same address, but if two objects have the same address *and* the same type, then they are the same object.

Answer (score 19):

### "ARRAY ADDRESS AND POINTERS TO MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAYS"

**Lets we start with 1-D array first:**

- Declaration `char a[8];` creates an array of 8 elements.
  And here `a` is **address of fist element** but **not address of array**.
- `char* ptr = a;` is correct expression as `ptr` is pointer to char and can address first element.
- But the expression `ptr = &a` is **wrong**! Because `ptr` can't address an array.
- **&a means address of array.** Really Value of `a` and `&a` are same but semantically both are different, One is address of char other is address of array of 8 chars.
- `char (*ptr2)[8];`  Here `ptr2 is pointer to an array of 8 chars`, And this time 
  `ptr2=&a` is a valid expression.
- Data-type of `&a` is `char(*)[8]` and type of `a` is `char[8]` that simply decays into `char*` in most operation e.g. `char* ptr = a;`

  To understand better read: [Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both stores in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

**Second case,**

- Declaration `char aa[8][8];` creates a 2-D array of `8x8` size.
- **Any 2-D array can also be viewed as 1-D array in which each array element is a 1-D array**.
- `aa` is address of first element that is an array of 8 chars. Expression `ptr2 = aa` is valid and correct.
- If we declare as follows:

  ```
  char (*ptr3)[8][8];    
  char ptr3 = &aa;  //is a correct expression
  ```

  **Similarly,**
  `moreThings` in your declaration `char moreThings[8][8];` contain address of fist element that is char array of 8 elements.

  To understand better read: [Difference between `char* str[]` and `char str[][]` and how both stores in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-array-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444)

---

**It would be interesting to know:**

- `morething` is an address of 8 char array .
- `*morething` is an address of first element that is `&morething[0][0]`.
- `&morething` is an address of 2-D array of 8 x 8.

  > **And address values of all above three are same but semantically all different.**
- `**morething` is value of first element that is `morething[0][0]`.

  To understand better read: [Difference between `&str` and `str`, when `str` is declared as `char str[10]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

**Further more,**

- `void doThings(char thingsGoHere[8][8])` is nothing but void `doThings(char (*thingsGoHere)[8])` and thus accepts any array that is two dimensional with the second dimension being 8.

---

**About type of variables in C and C++:** (I would like to add in answer)

- **Nothing is pass by reference in C** its C++ concept. If its used in C that means author talking about pointer variable.
- C supports `pass by Address` and `pass by value`.
- C++ supports `Pass by address`, `pass by value` and also `pass by Reference`.

  Read: [pointer variables and reference variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852911/assigning-int-value-to-an-address/17852936#17852936)

At the end,

- Name Of an array is constant identifier not variable.

Comment: `void doThings(char thingsGoHere[8][8])` is nothing but `void doThings(char (*thingsGoHere)[8])` and thus accepts _any_ array that is two dimensional with the second dimension being 8 and thus "_accepts exactly a char 2-D array of size 8*8_" is incorrect.

Comment: @legends2k You are correct, you might edit, now I have corrected with some further references-Thanks Very much to correct me!

Comment: It's nice to see people of high reputation appriciate corrections, many simply correct the answer and ignore the comment.

Answer (score 5):

Nicely explained by Kerrek,

In addition to that, we can prove it by the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
 int a[10][10];

 printf (".. %p  %p\n", &a, &a+1);
 printf (".. %p  %p \n ", &a[0], &a[0]+1);
printf (".. %p   %p \n ", &a[0][0], &a[0][0] +1);
}
```

The Output is :

```
.. 0x7fff6ae2ca5c  0x7fff6ae2cbec    = 400 bytes difference
.. 0x7fff6ae2ca5c  0x7fff6ae2ca84    = 40 bytes difference
 .. 0x7fff6ae2ca5c   0x7fff6ae2ca60  = 4 bytes difference.
```

&a +1 -> Moves the pointer by adding whole array size. ie: 400 bytes

&a[0] + 1 -> Moves the pointer by adding the size of column. ie: 40 bytes.

&a[0][0] +1 -> Moves the pointer by adding the size of element ie: 4 bytes.

[ int size is 4 bytes ]

Hope this helps. :)