# Why these pointers are showing different addresses?

Tags: c, pointers

For the following code fragment:

```
 unsigned int *ptr[10];
 int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 *ptr=a;
 printf("%u %u",ptr,a);
```

i checked on codepad.org and ideone.com.On both compilers its showing different values of ptr and a

Comment: These 2 are different that's why showing different addresses

Comment: Looks like this homework is popular tonight on SO.

Comment: a similar question just answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910749/difference-between-ptr10-and-ptr10)

Answer (score 1):

With warnings on:

```
pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness
format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int **’
format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’
```

Answer (score 0):

When used in pointer context, `ptr` points to the beginning of `ptr` array, while `a` points to the beginning of `a` array. These are two different arrays that occupy completely different places in memory. Why would they be the same?

Of course, printing pointer values with `%u` is a crime. Use `%p`. That's what `%p`is for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a array of pointers

```
*ptr[10]
```

If you want to assign a to this go:

```
(*ptr)[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

`uint *ptr[10]` is equivalent to `uint **ptr` and assignment `*ptr = a` is the same as `ptr[0] = a` which assign `a` to first offset inside `ptr` array, it doesn't touch value of `ptr` itself...

You maybe wanted to used one of these:

```
ptr = &a;

// Or
printf("%u %u",ptr[0],a);

// Or
unsigned int *ptr;
ptr = a;
```