# what the difference between int* v[10] and int (*p)[10]

Tags: c++, pointers

Show me the difference between:

```
int* v[10];
```

and

```
int (*p)[10];
```

Please.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910749/difference-between-ptr10-and-ptr10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int* v[10];
```

This declares v as an [array of 10 pointers to int](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%2a+v%5B10%5D%3B)

```
int (*p)[10];
```

This declares p as the [pointer to array of 10 ints](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28%2ap%29%5B10%5D%3B)

Answer (score 1):

With

```
int* v[10];
```

the variable `v` is an array of ten pointers to `int`.

The declaration

```
int (*p)[10];
```

declares `p` to be a pointer to an array of ten `int`.