# Pointer of array, what is the difference between (*ptr)[] and *ptr[]

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, operator-precedence, pointer-arithmetic

I met a weird thing when I tried to understand the pointer tp this array

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    short tell[3]{1, 2, 3};

    short (*pas)[3] = &tell;

    cout << (*pas)[2] << endl;
    cout << *pas[2] << endl;

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I got two different values for the two outputs.

The first one is correct, which is 3.

However, for the second one, it seems it returns a random number which is different every time.

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: second one is undefined behavior. First one is equivalent to `pas[0][2]` second to `pass[2][0]`

Comment: Just enable warnings with `-Wall`. You'll get "warning: array subscript 6 is outside array bounds of 'short int [3]' [-Warray-bounds] 11 | cout << *pas[2] << endl;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a pointer to a whole array

```
short (*pas)[3] = &tell;
```

So to get the pointed object (array) you have to dereference the pointer like

```
*pas
```

Now this expression yields a lvalue reference to the array `tell`.  So you may apply the subscript operator to access elements of the array

```
cout << (*pas)[2] << endl;
```

The postfix subscript operator has a higher priority than the unary operator `*`.

that is this expression

```
*pas[2]
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
*( pas[2] )
```

It means you are trying to access an object (array) beyond the allocated array that results in undefined behavior.

If you had a two=dimensional array like for example

```
short tell[3][3] =
{ { 1, 2, 3 },
  { 4, 5, 6 },
  { 7, 8, 9 }
};
```

And initialized the pointer `pas` like

```
short (*pas)[3] = tell;
```

the  the expression `pass[2]` would yield the third element of the array that is `{ 7, 8, 9 }` In this case you may apply one more subscript operator to access an element of the array like for example

```
pass[2][2]
```

that contains the value `9`.

The above expression also can be rewritten without the subscript operator like

```
*( *( pass + 2 ) + 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example can be :

```
int *ptr[10];
```

This is an array of 10 `int*` pointers, not as you would assume, a pointer to an array of 10 ints

```
int (*ptr)[10];
```

This is a pointer to an array of 10 int

It is I believe the same as `int *ptr;` in that both can point to an array, but the given form can ONLY point to an array of 10 ints

Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910749/difference-between-ptr10-and-ptr10#:%7E:text=Reason%20for%20segfault%3A-,*ptr%3Da%3B%20printf) example.