# What is the meaning of these two statements char (*test)[10]; test = new char[4][10];

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

In c++

```
char (*test)[10];

test = new char[4][10];
```

what the meaning of above two declarations?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13910749/12416453

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \*ptr\[10\] and (\*ptr)\[10\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910749/difference-between-ptr10-and-ptr10)

Answer (score 1):

```
char (*test)[10];
```

The first line declares `test` to be a pointer to `char[10]`.

```
test = new char[4][10];
```

The second line creates a `char[4][10]`, an array with 4 elements of type `char[10]`, and assigns the pointer to the first element of this array to `test`.

It is similar to

```
 T* test;          // pointer to T
 test = new T[4];  // create array with 4 elements 
                   // and assign pointer to first element to test
```

Comment: Thankyou , I appreciate for your answer

Comment: Is `new char[4][10]` even legal? I've never seen a 2d array allocated with 1 `new` without using a typedef.

Comment: @RemyLebeau indeed it looks a bit odd, but I think it is fine. `using foo = char[10];
test = new (foo[4]);` looks less odd, but is just the same with an alias

Answer (score 0):

When you have an array then used in expressions (with rare exceptions) it is converted to a pointer to its first element.

So for example if you have the following array declaration

```
char arr[4][10];
```

then it is converted in an expression as for example used as an initializer expression to pointer to its first element of the type `char ( * )[10]`.

So you may write for example

```
char (*test)[10] = arr;
```

The operator new that allocates memory for an array also returns a pointer to the first element of the allocated array. So if you want to allocate an array of the type char[4][10] then you can write

```
char (*test)[10] = new char[4][10];
```

Here `char[10]` is the type of elements of the allocated array. So a pointer to an element of the array has the type `char ( * )[10]`.