# Two Dimensional Array Implementation Using Double Pointer

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, double-pointer

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_ARRAYS     4
#define NUM_ELEMENTS   4
#define INVALID_VAL   -1

int main()
{
   int index            = INVALID_VAL;
   int array_index      = INVALID_VAL;
   int **ptr            = NULL;

   ptr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*NUM_ARRAYS);

   if (!ptr)
   {
      printf ("\nMemory Allocation Failure !\n\n");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   for (index=0; index<NUM_ARRAYS; index++)
   {
      *(ptr+index) = malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_ELEMENTS); 

      if (!*(ptr+index))
      {
         printf ("\nMemory Allocation Failure !\n");
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   }

   /* Fill Elements Into This 2-D Array */
   for (index=0; index<NUM_ARRAYS; index++)
   {
      for (array_index = 0; array_index<NUM_ELEMENTS; array_index++)
      {
         *(*(ptr+index)+array_index) = (array_index+1)*(index+1);
      }
   }

   /* Print Array Elements */
   for (index = 0; index<NUM_ARRAYS; index++)
   {
      printf ("\nArray %d Elements:\n", index);
      for (array_index = 0; array_index<NUM_ELEMENTS; array_index++)
      {
         printf (" %d ", *(*(ptr+index)+array_index));
      }
      printf ("\n\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

There is no problem with my code. It works fine.

```
Output:

Array 0 Elements:
 1  2  3  4 


Array 1 Elements:
 2  4  6  8 


Array 2 Elements:
 3  6  9  12 


Array 3 Elements:
 4  8  12  16
```

I have a question about pointer arithmetic:

`*(ptr+0)` = Pointer to COMPLETE BLOCK (First Array)
`*(ptr+1)` = Pointer to COMPLETE BLOCK (Second Array).

But what is: `(*ptr+1)`?

GDB Output:

```
(gdb) p *(*ptr+1)
$1 = 2
(gdb) p *(*ptr+2)
$2 = 3
(gdb) p *(*ptr+3)
$3 = 4
(gdb) p *(*ptr+4)
$4 = 0
```

I am getting confused on this. Please provide me some explanation to resolve this doubt.

Comment: I don't see `(*ptr+1)` in this code.

Comment: No, Its NOT there. This is my Conceptual Doubt after writing this Code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`*(ptr+i)` is equals to `ptr[i]`  and 
`*(ptr+1)` is `ptr[1]`.

You can think, a 2-D array as array of array.

- `ptr` points to complete 2-D array, so `ptr+1` points to next 2-D array.

---

In figure below  `ptr` is 2-D and number of columns are `3`

Original figure made by Mr. Kerrek SB, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674094/array-to-pointer-decay-and-passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-functions?answertab=oldest#tab-top) , you should also check!

```
+===============================+==============================+====
|+---------+----------+--------+|+----------+---------+--------+|
||ptr[0,0] | ptr[0,1] | ptr[0,2]|||ptr[1,0] |ptr[1,1] | ptr[1,2]|| ...
|+---------+----------+--------+++----------+---------+--------++ ...
|            ptr[0]             |           ptr[1]              |
+===============================+===============================+====
   ptr
```

`*(*ptr+1)  =   *( ptr[0] + 1 )  = ptr[0][1]`

Understand following:

`ptr` points to complete 2-D.

`*ptr = *(ptr + 0) = ptr[0]` that is first row.

<del>`*ptr + 1 = ptr[1]` means second row</del>

`*(*ptr+1) = *(*(ptr + 0) + 1 ) =  *(ptr[0] + 1) = ptr[0][1]`

```
Array 0 Elements:
1  2  3  4
```

And GDB Output:

```
(gdb) p *(*ptr+1)
$1 = 2
```

that is correct `2` this can be read using `ptr[0][1]`.

Comment: I have no problem in understanding of *(ptr+1). In fact, I have written the above code myself. My problem is {*(ptr)+1}

Comment: Thanks Grijesh. But gdb shows a different output. I am updating my Question to include GDB O/P for *(*ptr+1).

Comment: No. it is still not clear to me. I also expected that (*ptr)+1 may go to SECOND Array Block, but it is going to SECOND Element of FIRST Array (Added GDB Output in the Question above.)

Comment: @SandeepSingh : please check know it I hope now understood to you.

Comment: @SandeepSingh what is status now

Comment: @SandeepSingh: welcom sandeep ..Initially it was my mistake I written wrong sorry for that. ...& Thanks to you. let me know if you have other doubt.

Answer (score 28):

```
                                 (*ptr)      (*ptr+1)     (*ptr+2)
                                   |            |            |
             __________      ______v____________v____________v____________
  ptr------>|   *ptr   |--->|  *(*ptr)   |  *(*ptr+1)  |*(*ptr+2) |       |
            |__________|    |____________|_____________|__________|_______|
 (ptr+1)--->| *(ptr+1) |     ____________ _____________ __________________
            |__________|--->|*(*(ptr+1)) |*(*(ptr+1)+1)|          |       |
            |          |    |____________|_____________|__________|_______|
            |__________|          ^             ^
                                  |             |
                              *(ptr+1)     *(ptr+1)+1
```

2D array with double pointers that means that you have a main array and the elements of the main array are pointers (or addresses) to a sub arrays. As indicated in above figure

so if you have defined a double pointer as a pointer of this 2D array let's say `int **ptr`

so `ptr` is ponting to the main array which will contains pointers to sub arrays. `ptr` is ponting to the main array that's means `ptr` is pointing to the first element of the main array so `ptr + 1` is pointing to the second element of the main array.

`*ptr` this means the content of the first element which the `ptr` is pointing on. And it is a pointer to a subarray. so `*ptr` is a pointer to the first subarray (the subarray is an array of `int`). so `*ptr` is pointing to the first element in the first subarray. so `*ptr + 1` is a pointer to the second element in the first subarray

Comment: +1  to your answer, your firgure is much clear then my. Kallel how to draw this fig. ?  do you use any tool?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way for creating 2-dimensinal array using pointer,assigning values and accessing elements from the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i,j;
int row,col;
printf("Enter the values for row and col:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&row,&col);
int **arr=(int**)malloc(row*(sizeof(int*)));
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    *(arr+i)=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
            //You can use this also. Meaning of both is same.
            //arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
}
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
for(j=0;j<col;j++)
{
    arr[i][j]=0;
}
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Yes. You have simplified the assignment of values to double pointer.  But there is a great danger to this simplicity in understanding a double pointer.  From looking at this code, many people can conclude that a double pointer to a variable is like 2 dimensional array.  But double pointer to  a variable is not same as 2-D array.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you mistypes, `(*ptr + 1)` is equivalent to `*(ptr + 0) + 1` which is a pointer to the second element in the first block.

Comment: No, I have NOT mistyped. I had confusion over {(*ptr)+1}. Your interpretation is correct (verified by GDB). But as per my understanding, *ptr = Pointer to First ARRAY BLOCK, NOT to any individual element. Then, (*ptr+1) may have gone to the beginning of second array. Please clear this doubt.

Answer (score 1):

`*ptr + 1` is address of `ptr[0][1]`

Because, we know

```c
ptr[0][1] == *(*(ptr+0)+1)
```

Now putting ampersand on both side

```c
&ptr[0][1] == &*(*(ptr+0)+1)
```

You know that ampersand with asterisk is like plus sign with minus sign? They get cancelled. So this becomes

```c
&ptr[0][1] == (*(ptr+0)+1)
```

Which is same as

```c
&ptr[0][1] == *(ptr+0)+1
```

Which is again same as

```c
&ptr[0][1] == *ptr+1
```

This is my first statement.