# Why is `*(multi + row)` producing a pointer address instead of a value?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Why is `*(multi + row)` producing a pointer address instead of a value? Im confused but there must be a good explanation, but i dont know still.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 10
int multi[ROWS][COLS];
int main(void)
{
    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            multi[row][col] = row*col;
        }

    }
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            printf("\n%d ",multi[row][col]);
            printf("%d ",*(*(multi + row) + col));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at this question, [Two Dimensional Array Implementation Using Double Pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974001/two-dimensional-array-implementation-using-double-pointer/13974117#13974117) Notice the figure in MOHAMED's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multi` has a type of the form "array of arrays", so in most contexts, it decays to a type of the form "pointer to array". After adding `row`, it still has "pointer to array" type, but possibly points to an array other than the first array (first row) in `multi`.

Now, applying the `*` operator to "pointer to array" results in an array type, which again decays to a pointer to its initial element. This pointer has type "pointer to `int`".

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't. `multi` is a two-dimensional array, so dereferencing the pointer which it decays into when you perform pointer arithmetic on it results in an array (which is `COLS` elements wide).

Steps:

1. `int multi[ROWS][COLS];` - here `multi` is a two-dimensional array.
2. `multi + row` - here `multi` decayed into a pointer of type `int (*)[COLS]`
3. `*(multi + row)` - this is equivalent with `multi[row]`, i. e. the type of this expression is `int[COLS]`.

Answer (score 4):

Because multi is a 2D array which evaluates to a block pointer.

```
*(*(multi + row));
```

should get you a value.

```
*(multi + row);
```

evaluates to a pointer to the row whose index is determined by 'row'

**Update**:

*A block pointer still contains an address like other pointers, but it's arithmetic operates on blocks instead of single elements e.g. a pointer to first row of an array. If you increment it, it would skip one row of array (rather than one element as in case of a normal pointer).*

Comment: I was adding explaination of block pointer. Why are people so fast with downvotes? Just added that. Please be patient in your assessment.

Comment: As far as the C standard is concerned, such a data type is called a "pointer to array [of N elements]" instead.

Comment: I am pretty certain the terms are interchangeable. I learned it in my first programming course in C, some 11 years ago. Let me look for a reference and will add that here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a two-dimensional array, you have two levels of indirection to go through before getting to the value.

Answer (score 1):

`multi` is an `array` of `integer array` i.e `int (multi[rows])[cols]`.

`multi` can **decay** to a pointer to `integer array`. so multi can decay to `int (*multi)[cols]`.

so when you do `multi+rows` you are doing this essentially

```
sizeof(int [cols]) + sizeof(int[cols])...`row` times
```

and when you dereference it you get a element of type `array of ints` i.e the `address` of the first element of the integer array that you got in `multi+row`. now add offset to this dereferenced pointer and then dereference again, you will get the element i.e

```
*(multi+row) /*call this x*/-->gives an element of type int[] and int[] can decay to int*.
*(x+cols) --> gives you the element.
```

Comment: Thanks!! is there a way to reverse engineer it? I mean to say: how do you declare a double pointer and end up initialing all the array elements?

Comment: if you use double pointers then too its the same way. declare like this `int **multi;` and use it as i showed above.but this has 2 immediate issues. 1) you need to have a memory allocated already, otherwise UB. 2) you need to do all the book keeping on where you are indexing. dont use double pointers if you can create 2-D array.

Comment: Thank you!! Sure this will help.