# behaviour of pointer ; char ** argv

Tags: c, linux, pointers, argv

when I was testing double pointer behaviour I got a result that I don't understand well.

==> code 1 :

```
int main (int argc , char **argv)
{

if(*argv+1 ==NULL)
{
    printf("NULL pointer \n");
    exit(0) ;
}
else
{ 
    printf("test double pointer[] : %s \n ",*argv+1);  

}

return(0);
}
```

====> result 1

```
root@root:/home/aa/test# ./geip 1255
test double pointer[] : /geip 
root@root:/home/aa/test#
```

===> code 2 :

```
int main (int argc , char **argv)
{

if(*argv+9 ==NULL)
{
    printf("NULL pointer \n");
    exit(0) ;
}
else
{ 
    printf("test double pointer[] : %s \n ",*argv+9);
}
 return(0);
 }
```

==> result 2 :

```
root@root:/home/aa/test# ./geip 1255
test double pointer[] : 55 
root@root:/home/aa/test#
```

==> result 3 :

```
root@root:/home/aa/test# ./geip 
test double pointer[] : ELL=/bin/bash 
root@root:/home/aa/test#
```

it seems that printf display from  n th word (1 and 9) 
how we can explain this behaviour of pointer ?

Comment: Since `argv[0]` is shorter than 9 bytes, `*argv + 9`, which is equivalent to `&argv[0][9]` invokes undefined behaviour. It happens to not crash (in your case), and whatever is stored there is printed.

Comment: This code is so broken it hurts my eyes.

Comment: It's just a note, but working as a root user is potentially dangerous.

Comment: This will help you further: [Two Dimensional Array Implementation Using Double Pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974001/two-dimensional-array-implementation-using-double-pointer) Specially the diagram given by [Mohamed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13974651/1673391)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using it wrong.

`*argv+1` will be interpreted as `(argv[0])+1` and since `argv[0]` is "./geip" you get "/geip".

`*argv+9` will be interpreted as `(argv[0])+9` but since `argv[0]` only has length 6 the outcome is undefined.

In your case, argv is probably stored as :

```
.  /  g  e  i  p \0  1  2  5  5 \0
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Which explains why `+9` gets you "55"

**But you should really forget that because it's never going to be useful!** This is undefined behavior and should not ever be used.

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt: it could be useful if we want to read word from n th character !!

Comment: @stack_A Yes, but you'd use `argv[0]+1` or `argv[1]+2`, not something else.

Answer (score 1):

`char **argv` is a pointer to a `char *` (sometimes referred to more simply as a string). You dereference this pointer when you do `*argv`. The result of this dereference is a `char *` or in other words it is the address of a `char`. When you do addition with the result, your code is computing a new address. So, for example while `*argv` would be the address of the first character in your string, `*argv+1` is the address of the second character in your string.

When you add in a number that is longer than the length of your string you are stepping out of "safety". Remember that C will let you do pointer arithmetic that takes you past the end of your string. In your second example you are asking printf to go 9 bytes past the start of `*argv` and print characters from there to the next `\0` (or NULL) byte. You are effectively reading arbitrary memory from your program's process space, which explains what is being printed.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually more than one problem.

1. please, please, do not work as a root. Just don't.
2. your syntax (`*argv + 9`) means literally: "defeference argv and move pointer 9 chars", and really, if you move 9 characters from `./geip 1255` you'll arrive to `55`. So either use `argv[i]` (`i = 1..N` denotes argument index) or if you want to do it the hard way, you must add parentheses: `*(argv + i)`.
3. try to format your code better - it will be more readable not only for stackoverflow guys, but also for you.

For example when you run `./geip a b c 123`:

- `argv[0]` is `string` holding program name - `./geip`
- `argv[1]` is `string` holding the first argument - `a`
- `argv[2]` is `string` holding the second argument - `b`
- `argv[3]` is `string` holding the third argument - `c`
- `argv[4]` is `string` holding the fourth argument - `123`
- `argv[5]` is NULL as argc will bw `5` (see comments)
- `argv[>5]` is not a good idea, because there are no more arguments. So you better check `argc` to see how many arguments there are.

Comment: The standard guarantees that argv[argc] is a null pointer. So in this case argv[5] is guaranteed to be a null pointer.

Comment: +1 for **Do not work as root**.  Especially, do not do experimental programming as root!

Answer (score 0):

You just do a pointer arithmetics:
**argv is a pointer to list of pointers
*argv is a head of the list

```
//char **argv is given from outthere
char *p;
p = *argv; // the same as "p = *argv[0]"
for (int i = 0; i < 100) {
  printf("Next: %s\n", p+i);
}
```

Try to run it and see the dump of memory, from head of the list to next 100 bytes.

Comment: May want to go with `%.2X ` instead of `%s`, it's less crashy