# Parsing pointer parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

This code take 5 strings and sort them in ascending way.

```
 void swap (char data[5][255], int i, int j) {
     char temp[255];
     strcpy(temp,data[i]);
     strcpy(data[i],data[j]);
     strcpy(data[j],temp);
 }

 void sort (char data[5][255], int n) {
     // * : first address contact
     int i, j;
     for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
         for( j = i+1; j > 0; j--)
             if(strcmp(data[j-1],data[j])>0)
             {
                 printf("%s",data[j-1]);
                 swap(data, j-1, j);
             }
 }

 int main() {
     char strings[5][255];
     char comp[255];
     int i, n;
     n = sizeof(strings)/sizeof(comp);
     printf("Enter 5 strings, max 255 chars each:\n");
     for(i=0; i < n; i++)
         scanf("%s",strings[i]);
     sort(strings, n);
     printf("Sorted data:\n");
     for(i=0; i < n-1; i++)
         printf("%s, ",strings[i]);
     printf("%s.\n",strings[i]);
     return 0;
 }
```

In addition of that, how can I possibly parse my static array **string[5][255]** to function by using pointer?
I tried that, for example,

```
void sort ( char **data, int i ) { ... }
```

but it throws out error like this.

```
incompatible pointer types passing 'char [5][255]' to parameter of type 'char **'
```

Is there anything I can parse my array using pointer?

Since array parsed to function its first address(pointer), I thought function will accept those expression. Please give me some advice to understand.

Comment: why **data wouldn't work? unlike char *data[255], Jekyll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674094/array-to-pointer-decay-and-passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-functions << see here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter you must pass is not a pointer to a pointer `char**`, but a pointer to a char array `char(*)[255]`

```
void sort (char (*data)[255], int n)
```

When you pass an array, you can omit the size of the first dimension

```
void sort (char data[][255], int n)
```

which is equivalent to `char(*)[255]`.

`char**` is a pointer, which points to another *pointer*. Whereas `char(*)[255]` is a pointer, which points to an *array*.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Olaf, but I can not understand why it is impossible. Is that because of array saving priority to do not allocate parsing parameters as an infinite way?

Comment: It is not possible, because these are different types. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Olaf, to sum up, function can not be point a pointer, but can point any other type (like array), right?

Comment: You can use pointer to a pointer as @Jekyll shows. In your case however, you just don't have one, but a pointer to array.

Comment: it's not `char *[255]`, but `char (*)[255]`. They are very different.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote you in the comment char[][] doesn't decay to char** but it decays to `char(*)[]` ( `char (*data)[255]` in your case) as the first element decay in a pointer which is not a "pointer to a pointer" but a pointer to an array of 255 characters. It is possible to use a char** pointer if you do something like this (c++):

```
char **array = new char *[N];

for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    array[i] = new char[N];
```

or using the malloc (c).

As @newact suggests it is important to distinguish between

`char *data[255] -> char *[255]data` = => "data is an array of 255 pointers to char"
And

`char (*data)[255] -> char [255](*data)` => "data is a pointer to an array of 255 chars"

Comment: I got it, Mr. Jekyll! Thanks. It helped me a lot!

Comment: `char*[]` is an array of pointers. very different from `char (*)[255]`

Comment: @newacct corrected the char*[] in char(*)[] in the description :).

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the difference between: `char **data` vs `char (*data)[255]`

Those are two different types because the allocation of memory may be different:

When `char **data` is used pointer arithmetic may not work properly, meaning data could be scattered all over the memory

When `char (*data)[255]` is used pointer arithmetic works perfectly because all elements of array are adjacent to each other

Comment: Thanks Mr. Daveel. Then if I assign array by using memory allocation like 'malloc', then is it possible to parse to double pointing function like, 'sort(char **data, int n)'? Because I remember I have tried parse dynamic array to pointer.

Comment: @Sogo Yes, if you will allocate your strings on the heap, then your sort(char **data, int n) will work

Comment: `char *data[255]` is not `char (*data)[255]`

Answer (score -1):

Try to make the following changes:

```
void swap ( char *data, int i, int j)

*(data + index1*255 + index2)
```