# Why p and *p giving the same address when p points to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was writing this program -

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{ 
    int arr[20]; 
    arr[0]=22; 
    arr[1]=23; 
    int (*p)[20]=&arr; 
    printf("address in p :%u:\n",p);
    printf("address in *p:%u:\n",*p);
}
```

The Output of this code is same for p and *p ! So far as I know *p is holding the base address of arr which is nothing but arr[0]!!! 
So *p should have give the output 22 ! But it's showing the same memory address like p is showing. Please tell me why this is happened? What is the reason behind it.
Codepad Site Link : http://codepad.org/LK7qXaqt

Comment: Use `%p` to print data pointers

Comment: p == &arr, *p == arr , *p != arr[0], same address of arr, &arr[0], &arr. (*p)[0] == 22 or **p == 22.

Comment: Closely [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p` is a pointer to an array of `20` integers. Address of first byte of array is said to be the address of the array. Dereferencing it will give the entire array itself. Therefore `*p` represents the array `arr`, so you can think of `*p` as an array name.
As array names are converted to pointers to its first element when passed to a function, `*p` is decayed to pointer to first element of `arr`. Therefore

```
printf("address in *p: %p:\n", (void*)*p);
```

will print the address of *first element* of array `arr` while

```
printf("address in p: %p:\n", (void*)p);
```

will print the address of the entire array (i.e *first byte* of the array). Since value of *first byte* and *first element* is same, that's why both are printing the same address.

For detailed explanation:  [image: Stack Overflow] [What exactly is the array name in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467726/what-exactly-is-the-array-name-in-c/24468853#24468853)

Comment: Thanks ! It's quite easy to understand now. :)

Answer (score 5):

Because p and *p points to same memory location only there types are different

```
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    | | | | | | | | | | | | |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
arr [                        ]
  p [                        ]
(*p)[ ]
```

If you print `p+1` and `*p + 1` you should see the difference

`int (*p)[20]` declare [p as pointer to array of size 20 of type int](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20%28*p%29%5B20%5D) so at the same time `*p` is the pointer to the first element of the array.

Address of first element and of whole array would be same.

Comment: But *p should give the actual value stored in the address holding in the pointer ? Is not it?

Comment: `p` is address of array, `*p` is address of first element (i.e. `int`) and `**p` is the actual value stored in zeroth index. Moreover `p+1` is address beyond array and `*p+1` is address beyond 0th element i.e. of element at first index.

Comment: @MohitJain; `*p[i]` will not give `arr[i]`.

Comment: @haccks Alias for `arr[i]` would be `(*p)[i]` because `[]` couples righter than `*` according to c precedence table. And I did not say `*p[i]` will give `arr[i]`. Did I imply it somewhere by mistake?

Comment: @MohitJain; I thought about this --> `*p[ ]`

Comment: @haccks Sorry If I was not clear. What I want to say is, `*p` points to 0th index (starting with `[`) and type of `*p` is such that it ends where the 0th element ends (shown with `]`). I would surround `*p` in a parenthesis to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to apply the address operator to an array, although it seems redundant. The result p is a pointer to array. Such a thing is under normal circumstances rarely encountered. As @Mohit pointed out correctly, the object it points to is the whole array, which implies that sizeof(*p) should be the size of the array (not of its first element).

*p logically is the array then; as usual it decays to a pointer to its first element (which is an int) when passed as an argument, e.g. to printf. Since it's the first element its location in memory is the location of (the beginning of) the whole array.