# is a==*a?? A query regarding pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int main()
{
int a[4][3] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120};
printf("%d",((a==*a) && (*a==a[0])));
return 0;
}
```

Prints 1 on the console.
Anyone has logical explanation??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arrays are converted to pointer when used in an expression except when they are an operand of `sizeof` and unary `&` operator. `a` and `*a` are of different types (after decay) but have the same address value.

> - `a` decays to pointer to first element (first row) of array and is of type `int (*)[3]`.
> - `*a` dereference the row pointed by `a` and further decayed to pointer to first element of first row. It is of type `int *`.
> - `a[0]` is representing the first row which is of type `int [3]`. In expression it decays to pointer to first element of first row and is of type `int *` after decay.

As the address of an array the address of first byte, therefore *address of an array*, *address of first row* and *address of first element* all have the same value. So, after decay, all of `a`, `*a` and `a[0]` points to same location.

Here is a graphical view of the above explanation:

[image: Stack Overflow] [What exactly is the array name in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467726/what-exactly-is-the-array-name-in-c/24468853#24468853)

Comment: Yes. It would. Read the answer.

Comment: Then how can i point to the first element i.e.10 using pointer?I mean printing ts value

Comment: Either by `a[0][0]` or `(*a)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is a==*a?

---

```
The answer is yes if the array a is multi dimensional array.
```

so what if it is single dimensional? let me give you an example.
    `void main()
     {
       int a[4]={1,2,3,4};
       printf("%d",((a==*a)&&(*a==a[0])));
     }`

- The answer in this case would be 0.
- This is because 'a' represent address of array or address of first element of array but *a represent value(pointer to that value). the address and value are different types so answer would be 0.
- But in case of multi dimensional arrays 'a' represented as a[0][0] because it represent pointer to the first element of first sub array of multi dimensional array.
   **So the answer is yes if the array is multi dimensional array**