# Difference Between *ptr and *(&ptr + 1)

Tags: c

I am new to pointers and learning basics of pointers. I want to know the difference between 
*ptr and *(&ptr + 1) from the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
     int *ptr = a;

     printf("*ptr = %d\n",*ptr);
     printf("&ptr = %p\n",&ptr);

     printf("(&ptr + 1) = %p\n",(&ptr + 1));
     printf("*(&ptr + 1) = %d\n",*(&ptr + 1));

     return 0;
}
```

From my analysis gcc produced the following output,

```
*ptr = 1    // as ptr = a, Ultimately *ptr will print the first value of array i.e. 1
&ptr = 0x7fffa7e97788   // Starting Address of array or address of first element
(&ptr + 1) = 0x7fffa7e97790   //address of next element in the array
*(&ptr + 1) = 1  // I want to know how this is getting dereffered
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What size is `int`, in your environment?

Comment: Size of int is 4 bytes

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888) may help you to understand this graphically.

Answer (score 9):

`&ptr` is the address of the pointer variable `ptr`. This address in unrelated to the address of the array.

`*(&ptr + 1)` is undefined behavior because `&ptr + 1` is one step past the address of `ptr`. Dereferencing such a pointer produces undefined behavior.

What you probably meant was `*(ptr + 1)`.

Comment: I am using 64-bit ubuntu and the difference between the addresses is exactly 8 byte that is 64-bit, and it is probably giving the next address as you can see but not the past address if i use (&ptr + 1). can you explain me why?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What do you mean by "past address"? Why would you expect to see a smaller (=past?) address if you add 1 to a pointer? Do you understand that `&ptr + 1` points to nothing?

Comment: Thank You very much I got it, Just I got a little confusion with address arithmetic with you explanation i resolved it.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the compiler placed defined objects on the stack the following way

```
--------------------------------
|   ptr   | a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | 
--------------------------------
```

Thus `&ptr` is the address where ptr is allocated. `&ptr + 1`  is the next address after ptr and at the same time it is the address of a[0].

Take into account that it is unspecified in which order the compiler has to place local variables on stack.

Also it seems that in the environment where the program was compiled `sizeof( int * )` that corresponds `to sizeof( *( &ptr + 1 ) )` is equal to `sizeof( int )` and in turn equal to 4. Or
`sizeof( int * )` is equal to 8 but `sizeof( int )` is equal to 4. As you are using format specifier `%d` in printf for expression `*( &ptr + 1 )` then exactly a[0] is outputed.

By the way you can check whether this scheme corresponds to the actual placement of the variables by printing

```
printf("(&ptr + 1) = %p\n", &ptr + 1 );
printf("(&a[0]) = %p\n",  &a[0] );
```

If the addresses will not be equal then it means that there is some arbitrary value at the address `&ptr + 1` that does not correspond to a[0].

As for the question in the title of your post

> Difference Between *ptr and *(&ptr + 1)

then `*ptr` corresponds to `a[0]` while using expression `*(&ptr + 1)` results in undefined behaviour because you are trying to dereference address after ptr.

Comment: (&ptr + 1 is the next address of the ptr and at the same time it is the address of a[0])? will you please explain me how compiler is doing this?

Comment: @arahan567 The compiler places variables on the stack one after another and if it is required then aligning their addresses. It seems that the compiler placed the array after ptr without any padding bytes after ptr. So the array starts at the address after ptr.

Comment: Since the OP reports sizeof(int) = 4 and sizeof(int *) == 8, it might make sense to give `ptr` a larger section in the diagram.  (eg, make the box containing ptr twice as big as the box containing a[0])

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` is a pointer and it points to some valid memory location in your case.

`&ptr` is the address of your pointer and it can be assigned to a double pointer

```
int **ptr1 = &ptr;
```

Else the address of your first element is given just by `ptr`.

If you want to parse through your array then have

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
printf("Value %d is stored in %p\n",ptr[i],(void *)(ptr+i));
}
```

`(&ptr+1)` being dereferenced leads to undefined behavior as this is not the memory which is allocated by you. `&ptr` is under your control not the location after it i.e. `&ptr+1`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems an interesting one. Firstly, as you would be knowing `*ptr` gives value of `a[0]`,`ptr` contains the address of `a[0]` and `&ptr` is the address of `ptr` i.e integer pointer variable.

With this in mind, when you print `*ptr`, the value of `a[0]` i.e. `1` will get printed, `(&ptr+1)` would be address one step after the address of `ptr` and `*(&ptr+1)` would print the value at the address `(&ptr+1)`. In above code,address of `a[0]` is immediately after the address of `ptr` (i.e `&ptr`). So when you print `*(&ptr+1)`, it would print `1` because `&ptr+1` is pointing to `a[0]`. This depends on the memory assigned to the variables.

Declare the above variables as global and `*(&ptr+1)` would print value of zero (if '*(&ptr+1)' is not pointing to any location because global variables are initialized to zero). Also, observe the difference in the address assigned to the variables, when declared as global and local . Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you shiva kumar you are right as global variables become the part of data segment we will get the garbage value. But here the case is with stack segment so probably i think there will be no issue with memory.

Comment: Global variables are initialized to zero and not garbage value.