# Why does dereferencing an array or not result in the same address?

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++, I wrote the following simple main:

```
int main() {
    char test[100];
    void* a = (void*) test;
    void* b = (void*) &test;

    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And it gives me the same result for `a` and `b`. Why is this? I would expect from the notation that the second be the address of the first..

Comment: Because in the `a` line, `test` is shorthand for `&(test[0])`, and what you are printing out is the fact that the first element of an array has the same address as the whole array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Comment: I'm not really a fan of closing C++ questions as duplicates of C questions (even if the principle is the same in both languages)

Answer (score 6):

In C++, arrays are converted to pointer to first element of the array. `test` is pointer to first element `test[0]`. `&test` is the address of entire array `test`. Although, the type of `test` and `&test` are different, their values are same and that's why you are getting the same value.

For example

```
int a[3] = {5, 4, 6};
```

Look at the diagram below:

[image]

For detailed explanation read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888).