# How pointer to array of character behaves?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have following code snippet in understanding the working of pointer to character array of specific length, with the following sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    char sports[5][15] = {

            "cricket",
            "football",
            "hockey",
            "basketball"
    };

    char (*sptr)[15] = sports;

    if ( sptr+1 == sptr[1]){

        printf("oh no! what is this");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How `sptr+1` and `sptr[1]` can be equal?As the first one means to increment the address,which is stored in `sptr` by one and the second one means to get the value at address stored in `sptr + 1`.

Comment: I can't get GCC (nor Clang) not to warn about the type mismatch (a compiler conforming to any C standard has to warn and even `gcc -traditional` does). Which compiler did you use?

Comment: @mafso i am using code blocks

Comment: That's an IDE, not a compiler. Gcc, Clang, MSVC are compilers, for example.

Comment: Its GNU Gcc , default one

Comment: So you got a warning (or even an error with e.g. `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror`). Why didn't you post it? Did you understand the warning? Searched for the warning? Technically, the code shown here is simply invalid and may even not compile. (Though the question and the answers given still apply for e.g. `if ((char *)(sptr+1) == (char *)sptr[1])`, which is valid code with well-defined semantics.)

Comment: @mafso yes i got a warning but i don't understand its meaning so that's the reason i asked this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sptr` is a pointer to array of `15` `char`s. After initializing it with `sports`, `sptr` is pointing to first element of `sports` array which is `"cricket"`.

`sptr + 1` is pointer to second element of `sports` which is `"football"` and `sptr[1]` is equivalent to `*(sptr + 1)` which is pointer to first element of `"football"`, i.e,

```
sptr + 1 ==> &sports[1] 
sptr[1]  ==> &sports[1][0]
```

Since [pointer to an array and pointer to its first element are both equal in value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888), `sptr+1 == sptr[1]` gives `true` value.

Note that the although `sptr+1` and `sptr[1]` have same address value their types are different. `sptr+1` is of type `char (*)[15]` and  `sptr[1]` is of type `char *`.

Comment: but how *(sptr + 1) is a pointer it should be the value of second element of string football that is f?

Comment: It is explained in detailed in the linked answer with this answer. Read that answer and if you find any difficulty then I am here.

Comment: i understand it better now, but please explain me about the third exception  of how array are not decayed into pointer when we have string literals.

Comment: @Rouftantical; Is that "exception" written there?

Comment: i mean to say "except"

Comment: @Rouftantical; String literal have type `char []` in C. Same thisg is happened to it when passed to a function.

Comment: please move this discussion to chat i have a small coding question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71386/discussion-between-haccks-and-rouftantical).

Answer (score 1):

While dereferencing the pointer compiler will do like this,

```
a[i] ==  *(a+i);
```

You can verify that using the printf statement.

```
printf("%p\n",sptr[1]);
printf("%p\n",sptr+1);
```

Refer this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

Comment: yes man look that's my question sptr[1] means *(sptr+1) then how it is equal to (sptr+1)?

Comment: Well you edited your question but it seems that you are also confused with that comparison. The above comparison is not equal to `'c' == 'c'`. That's a pointer comparison.