# Why Do I need that extra asterix using 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I know that if `arr` is an array then  `arr[i]=*(arr+i)`; and if is a 2D array then `arr[i][j]=*(*(arr+i)+j)`; So I have this code

```
main(){
    int arr[5][5];
    int arr2[25];   // same as arr[5][5];
    int i,j;


    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            arr[i][j]=i+j;
            printf("arr[%d][%d] is at %p\n",i,j,&arr[i][j]);
        }

    printf("*(arr+i)=%d\n",*(arr+1)); // why this dont work


    for(i=0;i<24;i++){
       arr2[i]=i;
       printf("arr2[%d] is at %p\n",i,(arr2+i));
    }

    printf("*(arr+i)=%d\n",*(arr2+1)); // prints 1 as expected
}
```

I know  that in C there's no such thing as 2D array, its basically a linear row major contiguous blob of memory. So I'm wondering why I cant print the value of 2D arr using *(arr+1), which means add `1*5*4` bytes to the base of arr and dereference the value at that address. I know that `**(arr+1)` works but I dont know why I need that extra asterix ? Also If I do this `printf("*(arr+i)=%p\n",*(arr+1));` is the same as I would use `(arr+i)` to interpret as an address

Comment: What happens with more magic potion ?

Comment: Does each one come with an Obelix?

Comment: What kind of black magic is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` is an array of arrays of `int`s. Its type is `int [5][5]`. So, the elements of `arr` is 1D arrays. When used in expression, in most cases, arrays converted to a pointer to its first element. In `*(arr + 1)`, `arr` is converted to pointer to `arr[0]`, i.e, first 1D array. Adding `1` will increment it by `5*4 = 20` bytes, i.e, next element of array `arr` which is `arr[1]`.

Since `arr[1]` is an array, it can't be printed (as a whole), but its address can be. `arr[1]` is itself an array and it will decay to pointer to its first element, i.e, `arr[1][0]`. To print its element you need another dereference which is acheived by `arr[1][j]` (`j` is columns).

`arr[1][j]` is equivalent to `*(arr[1] + j)` which is ultimately equivalent to `*(*(arr + 1) + j)`.

Suggested Reading: [What exactly is the array name in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888)

Comment: So basically `arr[5][5]` is same as `arr[25]` just when used in expressions `arr[0]`,`arr[1]`,`arr[2]`,`arr[3]` and `arr[4]` will have `int*` type?

Comment: @BsD; You can say. But, sometimes memory management differs in 1D and 2D array containing equal number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `*(arr+1)` = the type of `arr[1]` = `int [5]`, which will decay to `int*` when used in `printf`.

To print the pointer, use:

```
printf("*(arr+i)=%p\n", *(arr+1));
```

To print the object it points to, use:

```
printf("*(*(arr+i))=%d\n", *(*(arr+1)));
```

You can make your code easier to read by using:

```
printf("arr[1] = %p\n", arr[1]);       // Print the pointer
printf("arr[1][0] = %d\n", arr[1][0]); // Print the value
```

Comment: Type of `arr[1]` is `int [5]`.

Comment: This is all much clearer if you write `arr[1]` and `arr[1][0]`

Answer (score 2):

As you said, a 2D array in C is basically an array of 1D arrays. You might think of this as an array of rows.

The rightmost `*` will dereference the outer array, selecting the row you want.

```
*(arr+i)      //this gives me a pointer to the row I want
```

The `*` to the left of that will dereference in the inner array, selecting an element from the row.

```
*(*(arr+i)+j) //this gives me an element in the row
```

`**(arr+i)` is just a special case of the above where the column number `j` is `0`.