# Output of a code- behaviour of & in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I came across a code whoes output I'm not able to understand.The code is-

```
int main() 
{       
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};   

  int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1); 
  printf("%d ", *(ptr-1) ); 
  return 0; 
}
```

The output of above code  is coming out 6, but i think that it should be 1. Please explain why it is 6.

Comment: ints are 2 bytes. `&a+1` is only moving forward one byte in the memory address...it should be `&a + sizeof(int)`, basically.

Comment: It is technically undefined behavior because you are casting from an incompatible pointer, should be `int *ptr = *(&a+1); `

Comment: @MarcB No, that will point way out of bounds.

Comment: @MarcB: `int` is _at last_ 16 bits. It can be more, however. For typical 32 bit CPUs, it is most times 32 bits (4 octets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question "&a" is address of the whole array a[]. If we add 1 to &a, we get “base address of a[] + sizeof(a)”. And this value is typecasted to int *. So ptr points to the memory just after 6 . ptr is typecasted to "int *" and value of *(ptr-1) is printed. Since ptr points memory after 6,so ptr – 1 points to 6.

Comment: name of array in C gives the address(except in sizeof operator) of the first element. adding 1 to this address gives the address plus the sizeof type the array has

Comment: that is second element

Comment: @DeepakTiwari: There are more exceptions to automatically converting an array to a pointer. See [the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). That actually includes the reason you just gave in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`&a` is an address of array `a`. Adding `1` to it will increment it to one past the array (adding 24-bytes). Cast operator `(int*)` cast `&a+1` to pointer to `int` type. `ptr-1` will decrement `ptr` by `4` bytes only and therefore it is the address of last element of array `a`. Dereferencing `ptr - 1` will give the last element which is `6`.

Comment: Interestingly, both `&a` and `a` have the same address in memory. The difference lies in their types and how it reflects to _pointer arithmetic_. Nice answer (see no reason to downvote it)

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski; [Here is my explanation about `&a` and `a`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888)

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Detail "both `&a` and `a` have the same _value_".  `&a` has no address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `a` is an array having a type `int[6]`. Therefore, `&a` gives you the type `int (*)[6]`. It is not *same* as pointer to int, it is a pointer to `int` array.

So, `&a + 1` increments the pointer by one of the the *array size*, pointing past the last element of the array.

Then, taking the address in `ptr` and doing a `-1`, decreases the address by a `sizeof(*ptr)` which is `sizeof(int)`, which gives you the address of last element on the array.

Finally, de-referencing that address, you get the value of the last element , `6`. Success.

Answer (score 0):

Because `(int*)(&a + 1)` uses the whole array as the base type and adds 1 whole size of an array to the address , i.e. adding 24 bytes.

And when you do `ptr-1` since `ptr` type is int it will subtract only 4 bytes.
Its very important to remember the type of the pointer while doing pointer arithmetic.