# C programming Pointers and Arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5];
    printf("%p\n%p\n",a+1,&a[1]);
    return(0);
}
```

When the above code is built and run.
The output is:

```
0029ff00
0029ff00
```

Then when i change the 5th line from `a + 1` to `&a + 1`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[5];
   printf("%p\n%p\n",&a+1,&a[1]);
   return(0);
}
```

The output is:

```
0029ff10
0029ff00
```

what is being referred to when i include the ampersand (`&`) and does it have to do with the format specifier `%p`?

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: `a` and `&a` give the same address, but different types.  So `a + 1` moves by the size of an `int`, but `&a + 1` moves by the size of a 5 element *array* of `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("%p\n%p\n",&a+1,&a[1]);
```

In this line both address are different because `&a[1]` gives address of `a[1]` and `&a+1` gives address that is one past the last element of array .

`&a` give address of array and adding `1` to it adds *size of array* to base address of array `a`.

So basically , `&a+1` = Base address of array `a` + size of array `a` (that address is printed)

Comment: base address of array?

Comment: @Atom Address of first element of array `&a[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`&a[1]` is equivalent to `&*(a + 1) = (a + 1)` and that's why first snippet prints the same address value.

`&a` is the address of array `a`. It is of type `int (*)[5]`. Adding `1` to `&a` will enhance it to one past the array, i.e. it will add `sizeof(a)` bytes to `&a`.

Suggested reading: [What exactly is the array name in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24467726/2455888).

Answer (score 0):

Sign "&" is address of element after & sign so in printf,it will print out memory address of your element.

> and does it have to do with the format specifier %p?

%p is accessing to pointer(address that pointer is reffering to) and that's why you get values like 'x0000'...

Try using %d or %i for integer values in your tasks.

Comment: The values he gets are fine, and wrong speciffiers should not be used .

Answer (score -1):

The '&' means "address of", and the %p format means print the value as a pointer (address), which prints it in hex.  When doing "pointer arithmetic", when you add 1 to a pointer, the pointer is incremented (1 * sizeof(type)) where "type" is the type of data being pointed to.

Remember, in C, an array variable is a pointer.  &a is not the address of the array, but the address where the address of the array is stored.  So, when you add 1 to &a, &a contains a, which is a pointer, so (&a + 1) is (&a + size(a)), and since a is an array, it's the size of the array.  In this case, an array of 4 ints is 16 bytes.

Comment: "Remember, in C, an array variable is a pointer" – he better not remember such bulls**t. "&a is not the address of the array" – it absolutely is.