# C: pointer to 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

From what I understand:

```
int B[2][3];
int* p=B;
```

doesn't work because B isn't a pointer to int but a pointer to an array of 3 ints. But it does not contradict the fact that B still points to the first element in the array, which is an int. so why *p or *B does not contain the value of B[0][0]?

How can something be a pointer to "an array of ints"? a pointer can only point at a single address in memory, not at all 3 addresses. It follows that B should always point to the address where the first element is, doesn't matter how long the memory block is.

Please explain why my reasoning doesn't work because I'm having a hard time
fully understanding it. Thanks.

Comment: `int (*p)[3];` is a pointer to an array of 3 ints. `int (*p)[3] = B;` would be the correct syntax and you can use `p` the same way as you would use `B`, except that you can increment `p` and `sizeof p` will yield to a different result (thx @Olaf).

Comment: An array is not a pointer!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888) may help you.

Comment: @mch: `sizeof(p)` will yield a different result.

Comment: `int* p = &B[0][0]` works. `int* p=B[0]` is shorthand for the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` is an array of arrays of `int`.  It is not a pointer and therefore does not point to anything.  However, under most circumstances, where it appears in code, `B` is automatically *converted* to a pointer to the first element of the array.  That element is not an `int`, but an array of 3 `int`s.

> How can something be a pointer to "an array of ints"? a pointer can only point at a single address in memory, not at all 3 addresses.

You might as well ask how you can have a pointer to `int`.  In every C system I know, `int`s are wider than one byte, but bytes are individually addressible.  How, then, can you point to an `int` when the individual bytes in it have separate addresses?  Of course, the answer is the same for an `int` as it is for an array: the address of the overall object is the address of its first byte.

> It follows that B should always point to the address where the first element is, doesn't matter how long the memory block is.

Exactly so, but a pointer is interpreted according to the type of data it points to.  Pointers to different data types may even be represented differently.  Given your declaration ...

```
int B[2][3];
```

... the expression `*B` evaluates to an array of 3 `int`s, specifically `B[0]`.  This is not the same thing as `B[0][0]` any more than the first byte of an `int` is the same as the whole `int`.  In particular, `(*B)[1]` is a perfectly valid alternative expression for `B[0][1]`.

Comment: Scratching your head over why it is `(*B)[1]` and not `*B[1]`? -- it has to do with *operator precedence*. `(*B)[1]` where `()` has precedence over `[]` reading left-to-right (both have precedence `1`), results in the value of element `1` in  the thing pointed to by `*B`. Without the `()`, `[]` takes precedence resulting in what can be thought of as `*(B[1])` where you are dereferencing the pointer at element `1` in an *array-of-pointers*. Lesson: "the value of element `1` in  the thing pointed to by `*B`" is not the same as "dereferencing element `1` in an *array-of-pointers* `B`." Got it?

Comment: To expand on what it means that `B` is automatically converted to a pointer but is *not* a pointer: the sizeof an array is equal to the size of one element times the number of elements (so in this case, `sizeof(B)` equals  `2 * sizeof(int[3])`, which in turn equals `2 * 3 * sizeof(int)`, while the sizeof a pointer to a given type is fixed (to `sizeof(int*)` in this case), and doesn't know how many elements are in the array.

Answer (score 2):

> so why `*p` or `*B` does not contain the value of `B[0][0]`?

`B` is an array of `2` arrays of `3` `int`s. When used in expression, in most context, arrays are converted to pointer to first element. In expression

```
int *p = B;
```

`B` is converted to pointer to its first element. First element of `B` is an array of 2 `int`s, i.e. `B[0]`. Therefore, `B` is converted to pointer to `B[0]`.
Dereferencing a pointer yields the value of data type that pointer points to. In this case `B` points to `B[0]` and is of type *array of 3 `int`s*. Therefore, `*B` yield an array of 3 `int`s and not an `int` data (`B[0][0]`).

> How can something be a pointer to "an array of ints"?

Any data type can have pointers. Arrays are also data types and can have pointers.

> a pointer can only point at a single address in memory, not at all 3 addresses.

I am giving you a real life example to explain this.

You have a house named `B` having `3` rooms. The address of your house is `House no. 18, Steet x`. If someone ask you what is the address of your first room, then your answer will be the same as the address of house `B`. Though the address of your rooms and house is same, **House != Room**.

The same goes here. The address of `B`, `B[0]` and `B[0][0]` all are same but type of all three are different.

Answer (score 1):

"Pointers" in C are more than just the underlying number representing a (virtual) memory address, they also carry with them the data type.

In your case, `B` is of type `int[2][3]`. You can't assign that to an `int*` any more than you could assign a `char` to a `char*`.

Under the hood, `B` is obviously the address of the first element, and you can express to the compiler that that's what you're talking about by casting:

```
int *p = *B;
```

Or using complete type erasure:

```
int *p = (int *)(void *)B;
```

Note that neither of those actually emit any code (debug code aside). You're simply re-interpreting compile-only types.

Comment: one of the two typecasts are unnecessary in `int *p = (int *)(void *)B;`.

Comment: Oh right, cause it's C. I'm used to C++. Right, `int *p = (void *)B;` suffices. I'll leave it alone to make my point as clear as possible.

Comment: I'd prefer `&B[0][0]`, not `*B`.