# Difference between a pointer and its address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am just trying to unveil the secrets of C and pointers (once again), and I had a question regarding pointers and decaying. Here is some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int (*p_array)[] = &array;

    printf("%p == %p == %p\n", array, &array, &array[0]);
    printf("%p == %p\n", p_array, &p_array);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run that, I get this output:

> 0x7fff5b0e29bc == 0x7fff5b0e29bc == 0x7fff5b0e29bc
>
> 0x7fff5b0e29bc == ***0x7fff5b0e29b0***

I understand that `array, &array, &array[0]` are all the same, because they decay to a pointer which point to the exact same location.

But how does that apply to actual pointers, here `*p_array`, which is a pointer to an array of `int`, right? `p_array`should point to the location where the first `int` of the array is stored. But why is `p_array`'s location unequal to `&p_array`?

Maybe it is not the best example, but I would appreciate if someone would enlighten me...

**Edit:** `p_array` refers to the address of the first element of the array, whereas `&p_array` refers to the address of the `p_array` pointer itself.

All the best,
David

Comment: `parray` is a pointer variable. Your second example prints the *value* of the pointer variable (where it points to) and its own address (where the variable is stored). Aside: you should cast a pointer to `(void*)` to satisfy the `%p` format.

Comment: @erip Well, that question is about C++, this is C. While this particular behavior is the same, in general I don't think a question about a different language can make this a duplicate.

Comment: @szczurcio Sure, that's why I don't flag all C questions as dupes to C++ questions or vice versa. The fact that C and C++ treat pointers and references the same is the reason I flagged this.

Comment: @erip Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought reference variables (like ``&ri = 1``) don't exist in C, only in C++.

Comment: @DavidBecher They don't exist in either.

Comment: @erip Have a look here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B) - Therefore the question is not a duplicate of your referenced post, since there the user asked about references.

Comment: @DavidBecher You sent a link to a wiki page without indicating what to look at. I've removed the dupe suggestion, but this question *has* been asking many, many times before.

Comment: @erip I just don't understand why you are telling me there is no such concept of "references" in C++ (as opposed to C, which has pointers but no references) when there *actually* is such a thing (this is what the link was for).

Comment: @DavidBecher You cannot reference a number, you can reference a variable. i.e., `int i = 1; int &ri = i;` is legal in C++. `int &ri = 1;` is legal in neither C nor C++. In any case, the dupe has been removed. This is becoming chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is `p_array`'s location unequal to `&p_array`?

`&p_array` is the address of the pointer itself (`0x7fff5b0e29b0`), whereas `p_array` is a pointer to `array` and its value is the address of `array`<sup>1</sup>, (`0x7fff5b0e29bc`).

---

<sup>1. The address of the first element.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that array, &array, &array[0] are all the same, because they decay to a pointer which point to the exact same location.

No. You didn't understand. `array` is of array type and in most cases will convert to pointer to its first element. Therefore, `array` and `&array[0]` are same as an expression, except when operand of `sizeof` operator.   `&array` is the address of array `array` and is of type `int (*)[3]`. Read here in details: [What exactly is the array name in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888).

`p_array` is pointer to array `array` and store its address while `&p_array` is the address of `p_array`.

Comment: Note that when you print out `&p_array` the address you see is 0xC or 12 less than the other addresses. That is because these addresses correspond to locations on the stack, and `p_array` is located right above (stack grows down) `array`. Since `array` takes up 12 bytes in this case, the difference in the addresses ends up being 12.

Comment: That is what I was trying to say - I am aware, that ``array`` is of type ``int[]``, but in most cases decays to a pointer to its first element (with ``sizeof`` being an exception to the rule). I just wrote it that way to simplify ;) But thanks for clarifying my second example, that seems obvious actually. I think I have been reading to much about pointers today, those beasts can be confusing sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You simply introduced another variable. As such it has a value ( 0x7fff5b0e29bc ) and an address ( 0x7fff5b0e29b0 ). This will be so for any variable you introduce