# Printing the address of the first element of 2D array in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, multidimensional-array, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()  
{
    int  arr[4][5] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                      {6, 7,8, 9, 10},
                      {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                      {16, 17,18, 19, 20}
                     };
    printf("%p\n", arr);
    printf("%p\n",*arr);

    return(0);
}
```

My doubt is that when I print arr and *arr it is printing same value. Why is this happening?

Comment: can you please check again, I've updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is an array of arrays of `int`. As per the array to pointer conversion rule, `arr` in `printf(“%p\n”, arr);` will decay to pointer to its first element. First element of array `arr` is of type `int [5]`, i.e an array of 5 `int`. Therefore, it will print the address of first element of the array `arr` (address of `arr[0]`).

Dereferencing, `arr` will return the first element of `arr`. This first element is of type `int [5]` as discussed earlier. So `*arr` will return an array of 5 `int` but again as per the array to pointer conversion rule `*arr` will decay to pointer to it's first element which is `arr[0][0]`.

So, in fact first `printf` is printing the address of the array `arr[0]` while later prints the address of the element `arr[0][0]`.

To understand why both these addresses are same I would suggest you to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468853/2455888).

Comment: Man you're awesome your comment cleared all of my doubt..!!!!  Thanks for the Answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%p\n", arr);
printf("%p\n",*arr);
```

At the first example, `arr` decays to a pointer to the first element in the first dimension of the two-dimensional array `arr` (the first `int` array of 5 elements - type (`int[5]`)) which also decays to a pointer to its first element which is `a[0][0]`.

At the second example you explicitly address the first element of the first dimension (which is of type `int[5]` - `int` array of 5 elements) and this one also decays to a pointer to its first element, which is again `a[0][0]`.

So both have exactly the same result - Access and print the address of the first element of the first array at the first dimension of `arr` - `arr[0][0]`.

---

Note that you need to cast the pointer to `void`, to make the program C-standard-conform as the standard implies that the `%p` format specifier needs to have an associated argument of type `void*`:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*) arr);
printf("%p\n", (void*) *arr);
```

Quote from ISO:IEC 9899:2018 (C18), Section 7.21.6.1/8:

> *"p - **The argument shall be a pointer to void**. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner."*

Comment: why do they have same address i mean ? can you share any where i can study this deeply?

Comment: For example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays)  you can find some information. Basically an array is a constant pointer, which is auto-dereferenced each time you access it.

Comment: @SanjayVerma The array `arr´ decays to a pointer to the first elemet of array `arr`. The first element always has the same address, doesn´t matter if you explicitly address or if address it via the array to pointer decay.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio; `arr` and `*arr` not giving the address of the same element. Though address is same, both giving the address of different objects. Your answer is misleading.

Comment: @haccks Hmm, I edited my answer a little bit. You mean `arr[0]` addresses is a different object than `a[0][0]` ? - I think it is the same object even though its representation is different. Do you got any reference to that from the standard?

Answer (score 0):

because you should know that name of any array means the first address of this array say

```
 int arr[4]; 
printf("%p",arr);// the same as printf("%p",&arr[0]);
```

and with respect to 2D array also the name of array acts as visuals pointer which points to the address of the first element in array

````````````````
int arr[4][5]; 
printf("%p",&arr[0][0]);//the same as printf("%p",arr);=printf("%p"*arr);
```````````````
````````````````