# C two dimensional arrays: Is the first 'level' an array of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

In C we have two dimensional arrays, i.e. `a[m][n]`.

In one dimensional arrays `a` is a pointer to the start of the array.

What about two dimensional arrays? Does `a[i]` hold a pointer to the start of the `i` row in an array? And thus `a[i]` is an array of pointers that is passed to a function in the following matter `function(int **a, m, n)`?

Comment: "*In one dimensional arrays a is a pointer to the start of the array.*" No, it isn't.

Comment: `a[m][n]` is an array of arrays.

Comment: a is a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski: No, `a` is an array in all cases the OP mentions. "*Arrays are not Pointers!*"

Comment: @alk: I understand that, but a does point to the first array element does it not?

Comment: no, I meant that the variable a is a synonyme of pointer to its first element

Comment: this is an exact excerpt from C language by Kernighan and Ritchie

Comment: @Dean: If an array is used without an index it *decays* to a pointer to its 1st element.

Comment: The answer to your question can be found [somewhere over here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/). I'm too lazy to look it up, eh...

Comment: @alk Not always. It decays when it has to and can.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12674094/694576

Comment: @juanchopanza: Fair enough - ... else you get an error.

Comment: @alk Or it doesn't have to decay, so it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a[i] hold a pointer to the start of the i row in an array?

No. The data of a 2D array in C is a contiguous block of elements plus some clever indexing access. But a 2D array is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.

Formally, the `a[i]` holds a 1D array. This may decay to a pointer to the first element of the ith row in certain contexts, but its type is still `T[n]`, for some type `T` that you have not specified.

Comment: 1D array of pointers, each points to the first element of the 'second level' arrays.

Comment: @Dean Yes, what about it? What on earth are you trying to say? A black dog on a hill.

Comment: I wanted to get is straight what each array contains, it's perfectly clear from the answer now, thanks.

Comment: @Dean Each array contains `i` number of items of the given type, no more, no less. There are no pointers anywhere. (Unless of course you declare an array of "pointers-to-type".)

Comment: Unfortunately during a C course they presented a multidimensional array as an array of pointers, which point to the first elements of array, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Dean Are you sure it wasn't in fact an array of pointers? You can actually have an array of pointers, where every pointer *can* be made to point to another array. But if that wasn't the case, it is a terrible way to explain 2D arrays!

Comment: Pretty sure. I believe they meant that it acts in similar fashion to an array of pointers, and it simply wasn't stressed enough.

Answer (score 1):

> In one dimensional arrays a is a pointer to the start of the array.

Not correct. `a` is an *array*. When you use `a` in an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to the first element. To better understand this, [read this chapter of the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html), particularly [this one](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

> What about two dimensional arrays? Does a[i] hold a pointer to the start of the i row in an array?

No. In a 2D array, `a[i]` is an array, while `int a[x][y];` is an array of arrays. There are no pointers anywhere.

You might be confused because C allows this syntax: `int a[][N] = ...;`, but that syntax merely means that the size of the array of arrays depends on the number of items in the initialization list.

Comment: "When you use a in an expression". Surely it depends on the expression. For example, if the expression is the RHS of an assignment to a pointer to array, then it doesn't decay.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, yes, but it doesn't seem very helpful to drag all the details of that into this answer, given that the OP is a beginner.

Comment: Shouldn't a[x][y] be an element, not an array of arrays?

Comment: @rcgldr Aah well yeah good point. It depends on the context. `int a[x][y];` is an array of arrays, while `a[x][y] = 0;` indeed refers to one item of the array. Edited my answer for clarification