# C *argv[] and char array[][]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Im completely stuck on how to convert a output from one of my functions of `char fileParameters[10][10]` into the format of `*argv[]` to pass into another function that expects the same format of `argv`. The purpose of this is to pass a file input through the same parser that parses command line input.

I understand `argv` is a array of pointers but I'm getting confused as aren't all arrays a pointer to the first element?

So therefore `fileParameters[10][10]` is a pointer to a pointer and if take the address using `&` then I expected an array of pointers? I've tried everything and whatever I do results in a segfault.

Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Please post a code example, otherwise it's not quite clear what you do and what fails.

Comment: They're not the same. An array is not a pointer.  And array of arrays is not the same as an array of pointers.

Comment: The problem here is that e.g. `char *[]` will decay to a pointer to a pointer, `char **` (which is why you can use both styles for `argv` arrays), and the array you have is a `char [10][10]` will decay to a pointer to an array `char (*)[10]`, which [is not the same as a pointer to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array to pointer decay and passing multidimensional arrays to functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674094/array-to-pointer-decay-and-passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-functions)

Answer (score 1):

> I understand argv is a array of pointers but im getting confused as arent all arrays a pointer to the first element?

No. Arrays can be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element, but they are not the same thing. You can easily tell by the fact that after `char a[10];`, `sizeof a` will give `10` rather than `sizeof(char*)`. Your `char[10][10]` is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.

You need to convert your array to an array of pointers:

```
char fileParameters[10][10];
// ...
char *fileParameterPtrs[10];
for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++)
  fileParameterPtrs[i] = fileParameters[i];
```

and then you can pass `fileParameterPtrs` to the code that is expecting an array of pointers.

---

@Vasfed rightly adds that you mentioned "that expects the same format of `argv`". This doesn't mean just any array of pointers, it means an array of pointers that is terminated by `NULL`. Your original `fileParameters` cannot hold any `NULL` value, so you will need to add one yourself. If all 10 parameters are filled, this is as simple as changing `fileParameterPtrs`'s length to `11` and adding one more assignment. If you have some other way of keeping track of how many `fileParameters` are used, adjust the code accordingly.