# Retrieving 2D array from pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I tried the following code

```
    char arr[5] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;
    printf("%c\n", p_arr[0][4]); //returns 'U'
```

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674094/array-to-pointer-decay-and-passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-functions) stackoverflow thread,

```
    char (*p_arr2D)[m] = &arr2D //or arr2D
```

is also a syntax for the decay of a `n*m` 2D-array `arr2D`, returning a pointer to its first element, an array of `m` elements.

`p_arr[0]` seems to be the "reverse" array decay, retrieving a 2D array from a pointer to an array. How can that happen ? In the code snippet above, is `p_arr` interpreted as a `1*5` array (from the original 1D-array with 5 elements) ?

Comment: My bad, I split my original question in two halves and forgot to change `char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;` to `char (*p_arr)[5] = &arr;` in this part. However, `char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;` doesn't create any compilation error (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687759/pointer-to-2d-array-with-incompatible-row-length)), and i don't understand why.

Comment: (The C compiler does not prevent what you want to do.) Compile it with `-Wall` option.

Comment: I did a rollback of code changes. Please don't fix things your code once answers have been posted. By fixing it, you rendered most answers irrelevant. Instead, if you have a follow-up question, ask a new question (like you did).

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, the line `char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;` is not valid C. Your compiler must give a diagnostic message. `p_arr` is an array pointer to an array of 1 char, but you assign it to point at an array of 5 char.

As for why it seems like you have a 2D array - you *don't* have one - is because  `p_arr[0]` works like any other pointer arithmetic, giving you pointed-at item "offset + 0". Which is the array. And then you access item 4 in the array.

A simple example of the very same pointer arithmetic principle would be this:

```
int a;
int* ptr = &a;
ptr[0] = whatever; // perfectly valid C
```

`ptr[0]` is guaranteed to be equivalent to `*(ptr+0)`.

Correct use of the array pointer should be `printf("%c\n", (*p_arr)[4])`. In this case it happened to work, but in other cases you might invoke undefined behavior, since `p_arr` is not allowed to point beyond the allocated memory.

Comment: My bad, I split my original question in two halves and forgot to change char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr; to char (*p_arr)[5] = &arr; in this part (done now). However, char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr; doesn't create any compilation error (see my other question), and i don't understand why. I already put this comment under my question, tell me if it's a good or bad practice to duplicate it here. I'll remove it if needed

Answer (score 1):

a 2D array is stored in memory like a 1D array [How are multi-dimensional arrays formatted in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

the `char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;` creates a pointer to an array of `char` pointers with one element (  `(*p_arr)[1]`  ) and by the assignment `&arr` this pointer gets the address of an already existing array with 5 elements

so `printf("%c\n", p_arr[0][4]);` prints the 5th element ( U ) because by `p_arr[0][4]` adresses the 5th element in line 1

`printf("%c\n", p_arr[1][4]);` would give an error

so the reason why this code works is that a 2D array is stored in memory like a 1D array

Comment: "and by the assignment &arr this pointer gets the address of an already existing array" No, because that part is not valid C. It is not a valid assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;
```

is incorrect because the declared pointer and the initializer have incompatible types. There is no implicit conversion from the type `char ( * )[5]`, the type of the initializer, to the type `char ( * )[1]`, the ty[e of the declared pointer. So you need an explicit casting to reinterpret a pointer of one type as a pointer of another type as for example

```
char (*p_arr)[1] = ( char ( * )[1] )&arr;
```

As for your question then if you have an object of type `T` where `T` is some type

```
T obj;
```

and a pointer to the object like

```
T *ptr = &obj;
```

then expression `*ptr` or `ptr[0]` yields the referenced object of the type `T`.

So let's assume that you have the following declarations

```
char arr[5] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
char (*p_arr)[5] = &arr;
```

For the type `char[5]` that is the type of the variable `arr` you can introduce a typedef name.

```
typedef char T[5];
```

Then the declarations will look like

```
T arr = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
T *p_arr = &arr;
```

As it was mentioned above the expression `*p_arr` or `p_arr[0]` yields the referenced object of the type `T` that is of the type `char[5]`.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an
>   object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand
>   has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
>   unary * operator is undefined.

And (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. **The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).** Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

and at last (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 7 For the purposes of these operators, **a pointer to an object that
>   is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the
>   first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as
>   its element type**.

So in this declaration

```
char arr[5] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
char (*p_arr)[5] = &arr;
```

the pointer `p_arr` does not point to an array element. However it can behaves as it points to the first element of an array of length 1. You can imagine it the following way

```
char arr[1][5] = { {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'} };
char (*p_arr)[5] = arr;
```

So the expression `p_arr[0]` gives the first element of the imagined two-dimensional array  that is an element of the type `char[5]`.

Comment: My bad, I split my original question in two halves and forgot to change char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr; to char (*p_arr)[5] = &arr; in this part (done now). However, char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr; doesn't create any compilation error (see my other question), and i don't understand why. I already put this comment under my question, tell me if it's a good or bad practice to duplicate it here. I'll remove it if needed

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring p_arr to be a pointer to an array of chars (and that array is of length one which is a sure sign of a problem).

You may want the much simpler syntax:

```
char *p_arr = arr;
```

or maybe:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char arr[] = {"Hello world"};
    char *p[3] = {NULL, arr, NULL};

    printf("%s %c\n", p[1], p[1][3]);
}
```

John

Comment: My bad, I split my original question in two halves and forgot to change char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr; to char (*p_arr)[5] = &arr; in this part (done now). However, char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr; doesn't create any compilation error (see my other question), and i don't understand why. I already put this comment under my question, tell me if it's a good or bad practice to duplicate it here. I'll remove it if needed