# Pointer to 2D array with incompatible row length

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I tried the following code

```
    char arr[5] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;
    printf("%c\n", p_arr[0][4]); //returns 'U'
```

Why isn't there any error, since

```
    char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;
```

seems to be an initialization from an incompatible type (`char (*)[5]` instead of required `char (*)[1]`)? Moreover, `p_arr[0][4]` asks for the 5th element of an array supposed to have only `1` element. Isn't that wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that builds? The types of `p_arr` and `&arr` are different, that initialization should not be allowed.

Comment: As for what I think your question is, C have no bounds checking.

Comment: By _"C have no bounds checking"_ do you mean that the C compiler doesn't use the `[1]` information in ` char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;`. If that is the case, isn't there a problem with C's static memory allocation ?

Comment: Yes, I double checked this and it builds

Comment: Take you array `arr` for example, it has 5 elements meaning its valid indexes are `0` to `4` (inclusive). However, the compiler is not required to complain if you use `arr[5]` in an expression. While the compiler keeps track of the size for use in `sizeof`, what happens when it does `arr[5]` is really `*(arr + 5)`, which is *pointer arithmetic*. And pointers have no inbuilt knowledge of the data it points to except the type. More specifically, pointers have no knowledge of the *size* of the data it points to. In other words, no bounds checking.

Comment: That's how C works, and it is your responsibility as a programmer to not go out of bounds of memory (arrays of dynamically allocated) you have. Not doing explicit bounds-checking in your program can and will lead to out-of-bounds access, and that in turn leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Indeed, but in this case, it means that I can validly access `p_arr[1]` although only `p_arr[0]` refers to data I entered. However, doesn't `char (*p_arr)[1]` expect a pointer to an array of size 1 which keeps track of the size of the data since it is an array ?

Comment: I'm no longer sure what your question is... Is it about the initialization of `p_arr` from an incompatible type? Then it's [answered below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46688779/440558). Or is it about the apparently out-of-bounds access of `p_arr[0][4]`?

Comment: And what is the difference between this question and your previous question?

Comment: Right, i'll edit my question to make it clearer since it was about both of these points. The out-of-bounds access to `p_arr[0][4]` was indeed answered to below, now the part that remains is about the initialization of `p_arr` from incompatible type

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is broken/incorrectly configured/non-compliant.

An array pointer to an array with 1 element is not compatible with an array pointer to an array of 5 element. The rule of *simple assignment* in C says that a valid pointer assignment must be (C11 6.5.16.1 emphasis mine):

> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
>     conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified
>     versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has
>     all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

If we remove all the formal standard terms from the cited text, we end up with this in plain English:

*The left operand of the = operator has pointer type, and both operands are pointers to compatible types.*

This is not the case in your code, so it contains something known as *constraint violation*, meaning that the code violates what's allowed by the C standard.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the C compiler not checking bounds for the `p_arr[0][4]` part.

Comment: Have you tried executing the `char (*p_arr)[1] = &arr;` part of the code ? I downloaded codeblocks IDE on their website, are you sure my compiler is broken/non-compliant ?

Comment: @Y.GP After testing it myself, the compiler emits a *warning* about incompatible types for the assignment. But you have to remember that C is rather weakly typed, which is probably the reason it's not an error.

Comment: @Y.GP To use the gcc compiler as a _standard C compiler_, you must use settings `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. In Codeblocks, Settings -> Compiler -> Compiler settings tab. Check "Treat as errors the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++". It is also a good idea to check "Enable extra compiler warnings" (-Wextra) and "Enable all common compiler warnings (overrides many other settings)" (-Wall"). However, even if you didn't do this, gcc gives a warning as it must. Listen to the compiler.