# no known conversion from 'const int [5][4]' to 'const int **' in a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, data-conversion

I have a class with this constructor:

```
Dfa(const int n_state, const int dim_alf, const string *alf, const int s_state, const int** tt_copy );
```

I try to create a dfa object like this:

```
const string alph[3] = {"a","b","c"};
const int ttable[5][4] = {1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 4, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0};
Dfa reference_Tomita15 = new Dfa(5,3,alph,0,ttable);
```

This code gives me the error:

```
candidate constructor not viable: no
  known conversion from 'const int [5][4]' to 'const int **' for 5th argument
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you all for the attention

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays don't decay to pointers as one-dimensional arrays do (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674094/array-to-pointer-decay-and-passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-functions). Can you change the constructor?

Comment: @Jens Strictly saying, they do decay to pointers in the exact same way as 1D arrays. But the resulting pointer type could be different from what you expect: `int [5][4]` becomes `int (*)[4]`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. No I cannot change the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, I would first create a class for the transition table, and then change the constructor to use that instead of a C-array to

```
class transition_table {
};

Dfa(int n_state, int dim_alf, const string& alf, int s_state, transtition_table tt)
```

If you create it from a statically allocated array, you can do

```
template<size_t DIM> Dfa(int n_state, const string& alf, int s_state, int (&tt)[DIM][DIM])
```

or even better

```
template<size_t DIM> Dfa(int n_state, const string& alf, int s_state, std::array<std::array<int, DIM>, DIM> tt)
```

I assume that the transition table is quadratic.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a really good point, I'll give it a try :)