# Why do C++/CLI jagged managed array initializers allocate huge temporary arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I was profiling a C++/CLI project at work that had a strange memory signature: it had a huge amount of Commited bytes (7GB) but it only had about 30MB in the Working Set. What I discovered was that the problem lay in something like this piece of code:

```
ref class c1
{
public:
    int x;

    static void createArray()
    {
        auto val = gcnew c1;
        auto arr = gcnew array<c1^>(1) { val };
        auto jagged= gcnew array<array<c1^>^>{ arr };

        //Make sure the array doesn't get optimized away
        Console::WriteLine(jagged[0][0]->x);
    }
};
```

I was expecting the initialization of jaged to translate to something like this in C#:

```
var jagged = new c1[][] { arr };
```

Instead, using ILSpy, I discovered it actually translates to something like this (decompiling the **optimized** binaries:

```
public static void createArray()
{
    c1 val = new c1();
    c1[] array = new c1[]
    {
        val
    };
    c1[][] array2 = new c1[][]
    {
        new c1[12648430] //the constant is equal to 0xC0FFEE
    };
    array2[0] = array;
    Console.WriteLine(array2[0][0].x);
}
```

I find it very hard to understand why it would allocate a 12648430 element temporary array. However, I also find it hard to imagine such a bug actually was released in the Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition MSVC compiler, but I can't think of any other explanation.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Wouldn't it be 
int jagged_row0[] = {0,1};
int jagged_row1[] = {1,2,3};

int (*jagged[])[] = { &jagged_row0, &jagged_row1 };

taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083658/jagged-array-in-c

Comment: Perhaps someone needed a caffeine boost.

Comment: It's not corrupted memory is it?

Comment: Programmers tend to use magic constants to initialize variables to an "unknown value" state.  Usually with a quip, 0xdeadbeef for example.  0xc0ffee fits that pattern.  This quacks like a compiler bug, initializer lists in C++11 would certainly help to destabilize code like this.  Your repro code is however not good enough to demonstrate the problem so finding a workaround is illusive.  You'll need help from Microsoft Support if you can't narrow it down.

Comment: @ThomasLindvall No, the answer you're linking to is about native C++ arrays. This question is about managed arrays in C++/CLI, a way of compiling C++ code for the .NET managed environment.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean that my repro code doesn't actually reproduce the problem on your machine? Anyway, the workaround is easy - don't use initializers, fill out each element of the array manually.

Comment: Tried it on VS2013 Update 2, release build with the optimizer enabled.  Worked fine, no coffee.  Your "myArrArr" didn't exactly help btw.

Comment: I was talking about var jagged = new c1[][] { arr };
but I'm a c++ scrub

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for taking the time to try this out (and sorry for the myArrArr, edited that now). It's very strange that it doesn't reproduce for you - I am compiling  exactly the code I attached (+ a main function) using VS2013 update 2 as well, and using /Ox. It also reproduces both when compiling for x86 and for x64. I will probably talk to some co-workers on Monday and see if it happens on their setups as well or not. Once again, thanks for your time in looking at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the C++/CLI compiler implementation. Microsoft is aware of the issue, but they won't fix it for a while.

Some more details can be found in the bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/884769/using-an-initializer-list-to-create-a-jagged-clr-array-in-c-cli-allocates-very-large-temporary-arrays).

The report also suggests two simple workarounds:

1. Manually initialize the array instead of using an initializer list.
2. Use two-dimensional arrays instead of jagged arrays.