# Jagged array implementation in C- error: expected ';' at the end of declaration list

Tags: c, jagged-arrays

I wrote a piece of C code as below:-

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int buffer_ctrl[4];
    unsigned int buffer1[10];
    unsigned int buffer2[40];
    unsigned int buffer3[20];
    unsigned int buffer4[15];
    unsigned int *buffer_ptr[4] = {buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, buffer4};
    unsigned int canary[4];
} buffer_t;
```

I wrote this in a header file which I included in a main code. I had read up a lot of examples on jagged array in C and thought this would work just fine. One of the links was [Do jagged arrays exist in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083658/do-jagged-arrays-exist-in-c-c).

However, when I compile I get the error "expected ';' at end of declaration lsit". Can someone please help explain what might be the error here? 
Thanks!

Comment: It will except `unsigned int *buffer_ptr[4] = {buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, buffer4};` -- you can't initialize member of a struct at the time of definition. (but you could use a `union` within the `struct ` to essentially do the same).

Comment: Inside a structure? That would not work, I believe.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You mean can't - right?

Comment: Yes, right -- you can't (that was meant to say all would work "except" ..).

Comment: Please *copy-paste* the error message verbatim. This does not help anyone if you typo the error message!

Comment: Thanks, it seems I was correct in thinking it was the initialization inside the struct that was the problem. I just wanted it confirmed that I was understanding things correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to `buffer_ptr` within the definition of the `buffer_t` structure itself. You have to define a variable of the type `buffer_t` first and then assign to it.

You can do something like this:

```
buffer_t bt = {
    .buffer_ptr[0] = bt.buffer1,
    .buffer_ptr[1] = bt.buffer2,
    .buffer_ptr[2] = bt.buffer3,
    .buffer_ptr[3] = bt.buffer4
};
```

Comment: There generally isn't a good reason to permanently store an array that is so easy to calculate, though. You can create such an array when you need it, and save memory when you don't.